# video not displayed in Xubuntu

Tags: video, xubuntu, display

I have Xubuntu installed in my PC. When I play a video after starting the system it plays fine. After some time the video is not displayed and I can only hear sound. If I reboot my PC then the video is again displayed. I installed vlc player but it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with video and discovered that turning off screen effects- i.e. the compositor, fixed the issue. Go to the Xfce menu and click settings > settings manager > window manager tweaks and click the compositor tab so that it looks like the screenshot below. Now your video should play fine- try it with `vlc` and `smplayer`, for example.

The compositor seems to interfere with video playback and particularly hardware accelerated video; as you describe, video will play for a few seconds and then goes black and you are left only with the audio. Your problem seems the same as mine, so this solution will probably work for you. I am running 12.04, but the settings should be in a similar area in earlier versions as well.

[image]

Comment: It did not solved my problem. I also noticed that the font color of my icons also changes and my PC also becomes a bit slow.

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings in both screensaver settings, advanced tab, and Power Management to insure video is not set to turn off. Either one is fully capable of shutting down video, and not all machines respond to a keypress to turn it back on. Also, as a test, try tapping the SHIFT key every 5 minutes. If the video does not turn off, then you need to find the setting that is causing it to shut the monitor off.

Comment: Actually I dont have problems with my display. the problem is when i play a movie through vlc player or any ather software to works fine at first, but after a certain time video doesnot work only i hear only sound. other applications work fine though.